# How to return a LINQ to SQL Table entity from a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, interface, return-value

The following method in my WCF implementation:

```
public Campaign GetCampaignByDisplayName( String displayName )
```

where `Campaign` is a table in my SQL Server database, my client app throws an exception when the above method returns. From other related posts, I've read that the problem probably has to do with `Campaign` not being serializable. Going into the generated database designer source file, and duly ignoring the admonishment "Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior..." I add the `[Serializable]` attribute to the `Campaign` class, resulting in a non-compilable Proxy file once that's regenerated.

Clearly I'm missing a critical concept here. What do I need to do to be able to pass a LINQ to SQL record in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark the Campaign class with `DataContractAtribute`.
Mark any members which you wish to be passed via the web service with the `DataMemberAttribute`.

There is a decent primer on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I'm also reading this from Scott Gu's blog: http://codeexperiment.com/post/Returning-LINQ-to-SQL-Entities-From-WCF.aspx which I found by pasting the title of my question into Google. Lesson reinforced: choose titles for your questions carefully!

Comment: My mistake: that's Scott Lanford's blog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **sqlmetal** use  */serialization:Unidirectional*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx